# Identity server 4 handling Expired or revoked refresh tokens

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I am working with an Identity server 4 system.  We are using the exact code from the [MvcHybridAutomaticRefresh](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Clients/src/MvcHybridAutomaticRefresh/AutomaticTokenManagement) sample

The issue is with this code here.  [AutomaticTokenManagementCookieEvents.cs#L73](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/samples/Clients/src/MvcHybridAutomaticRefresh/AutomaticTokenManagement/AutomaticTokenManagementCookieEvents.cs#L73)

```
var response = await _service.RefreshTokenAsync(refreshToken.Value);
    if (response.IsError)
       {
       _logger.LogWarning("Error refreshing token: {error}", response.Error);
       return;
       }
```

Currently if a refesh token was revoked by the admins, or the refresh token has expired ( we do not have sliding refresh tokens enabled) Then the application will crash.  I would expect it to reroute the user to the login screen.

I am i missing something in this sample that it cant handle that?

I have also posted this as a question on the issue forum [#3599](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/3599)

## current attempt

is to add The following rather where it detects the error

```
await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

which i had hoped would log the user out. This just hangs and never goes anywhere. Its not even logging you out of the server.

## Current Solution

The only thing i can find currently that remotely works is to add a catch in the api call.   This is not ideal as in our actual application we have a lot of api calls this would mean making a lot of changes to our application.  Isnt there a way to force a login directly from the middle wear itself?

```
[Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CallApi()
    {
        try
        {
            var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

            var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            client.SetBearerToken(token);

            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(Constants.SampleApi + "identity");
            ViewBag.Json = JArray.Parse(response).ToString();

            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new SignOutResult(new[] { "Cookies", "oidc" });
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you managing the session of the user inside the client application? If you're starting a new cookie session then you should end it so the user gets redirected to "outside" of the protected zone of your application and from there start the login flow again. That's what you get when you try to access any application with expired session, first it seems to get in but suddenly redirects you to login/main page

Comment: I tried calling logout from  AutomaticTokenManagementCookieEvents it doesn't work it just hangs.  If thats what you mean.  I think the issue is that the user is technically still logged in its the Oauth2 refresh token thats expired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add just one row to force the middleware to perform the challenge again:

```cs
if (response.IsError)
{
    _logger.LogWarning("Error refreshing token: {error}", response.Error);
    context.RejectPrincipal();
    return;
}
```

Comment: You are really are a life saver.  I have updated the sample code with your example.  Not sure why i didnt think of this.